# How to autoplay video through YouTube Player

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I am developing an app in which I have shown YouTube videos thumbnails in RecyclerView and there is YouTube Player fragment on top which plays the user selected video. I succeed in doing so. but the problem is that I want to auto play the user selected video. 
below is my code:
main_activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.pc.fkidshell.Main2Activity">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/VideoFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_thirdtoolbar"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/VideoList"
        android:layout_below="@+id/VideoFragment"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

secvideo_row.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thumbnailView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main_Activity.java:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener, YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    YouTubePlayerFragment playerFragment;
    YouTubePlayer Player;
    YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView;
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader;
    RecyclerView VideoList;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    List<Drawable> thumbnailViews;
    List<String> VideoId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        thumbnailViews = new ArrayList<>();
        VideoList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.VideoList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        VideoList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new Main2Activity.VideoListAdapter();
        VideoList.setAdapter(adapter);
        VideoId = new ArrayList<>();
        thumbnailView = new YouTubeThumbnailView(this);
        thumbnailView.initialize("AIzaSyAXlMCst9tNrTGz4xAZ0mY6mJlkNU-3DAs", this);
        playerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.VideoFragment);
        playerFragment.initialize("AIzaSyAXlMCst9tNrTGz4xAZ0mY6mJlkNU-3DAs", this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
        thumbnailLoader = youTubeThumbnailLoader;
        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(Main2Activity.this);
        thumbnailLoader.setPlaylist("PLXRActLQ03oY_6AQb-5EMuKFYQA_fDE40");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    }

    public void add() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (thumbnailLoader.hasNext())
            thumbnailLoader.next();
    }

    @Override
    public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
        thumbnailViews.add(youTubeThumbnailView.getDrawable());
        VideoId.add(s);
        add();
    }

    @Override
    public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        Player = youTubePlayer;
        Player.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
                VideoList.setVisibility(b ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    }

    public class VideoListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoListAdapter.MyView> {

        public class MyView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageView;
            public MyView(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public VideoListAdapter.MyView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.secvideo_row, parent, false);
            return new MyView(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(VideoListAdapter.MyView holder, final int position) {
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(thumbnailViews.get(position));
            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Player.loadVideo(VideoId.get(position));
                    //Player.loadVideo(VideoId.get(position));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return thumbnailViews.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the Youtube player is initialized, set a player state change listener so that you can play the video when the video is loaded and make sure your activity implements player state callbacks.
Detailed code :

```
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        Player = youTubePlayer;
        Player.setOnFullscreenListener(new YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFullscreen(boolean b) {
                VideoList.setVisibility(b ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        Player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(this); //set player state change listener
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String videoId) {
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(videoId) && Player != null)
            Player.play(); //auto play
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ErrorReason reason) {
        Log.e("onError", "onError : " + reason.name());
    }
```

Comment: hide() method in onVideoStarted shows me error to declare method although i have implements activity with YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener

Comment: remove the hide() method. I was using it for some purpose.

Comment: The selected video plays without letting the user to touch the play icon on video player. I want to play the same video again.

Comment: if you want to play it again, then you can call Player.play() in onVideoEnded() callback, but do remember, this will make a loop of playing same video again and again. I don't think that will be a good user experience

Answer (score 0):

i hade the same problem, i use YouTubePlayerFragment though and this is what i did.

```
  public async void PlayVideo(params string[] videoId)
    {
        if (YoutubePlayer != null && videoId != null && videoId.Length > 0)
        {
            YoutubePlayer.CueVideos(videoId);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // whait untill the files load.


            YoutubePlayer.Play();
        }
    }
```

and the player get assigned here

```
public void OnInitializationSuccess(IYouTubePlayerProvider provider, IYouTubePlayer player, bool wasRestored)
{
    if (!wasRestored)
    {
        YoutubePlayer = player;
        PlayVideo(elemnt.VideoSource.ToArray());
    }
}
```